# Recorrer las filas de una tabla realizada con Javascript y enviarlas al controller en laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola comunidad tengo una tabla que genero mendiante una funcion en javascript en la cual necesito capturar los datos de cada fila como la descripcion, detalle, cobro y el costo; posterior a ello enviarlo a un controller en laravel.

Mi consulta es como podria capturar los valores de la tabla para posteriormente mi controller pueda recibir esa data de cada fila y hacer el insert respectivo.

Este es mi codigo HTML ya generado con mi function de JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
        <thead style="color:#ffffff; background-color: rgb(33,136,201)">
            <tr>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Item</th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Descripción</th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Detalle servicio</th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Cobro servicio"</th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Costo total US <img class="img-fluid" style="height: 35px;" src="http://radiadores.test/images/iconos/dolar.png" alt="dolar"></th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></th>
                <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="text-sm" id="list-mano-obra">
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="1">
                <td class="fw-bold">Servicio de corte</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="500 láminas de aluminio"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">centimos</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="2">
                <td class="fw-bold">Servicio de troquelado</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="500 láminas de aluminio"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">centimos</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="3">
                <td class="fw-bold">Servicio de llenado</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="Operario llenador"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">soles</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">4</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="4">
                <td class="fw-bold">Parrillas</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="Sujetadores"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">5</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="5">
                <td class="fw-bold">Codos</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="66 codos en panel S/I"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">6</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="6">
                <td class="fw-bold">Oxigas</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="equipo de soldadura"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">7</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="7">
                <td class="fw-bold">Servicio de soldadura</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="soldar partes del radidor"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">8</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="8">
                <td class="fw-bold">Mano de obra</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="soldador"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">soles</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">9</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="9">
                <td class="fw-bold">Prueba de presión</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="nitrogeno - gas seco"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">10</th><input type="hidden" class="labour_id" name="labour_id" value="10">
                <td class="fw-bold">Trabajos de limpieza y acabados</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold description" name="description" readonly="" value="trabajo final"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center bg-light fw-bold valor border border-danger" name="service-charge" placeholder="Ingresar cobro servicio">dolares</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-center bg-light fw-bold" name="costo-total" readonly="" placeholder="$0.00"></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="cost_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_mano_obra(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a poder capturar todos los datos que tiene mi tabla ya generada.
Gracias